# WSDL definitions without namespace

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I can do in `WSDL` definitions that is not in any namespace?
I want do half objects have namespace and other don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want your elements to be without any namespace?

If you mean not prefixing any elements with any namespace, that is using the default namespace. You can read more about it [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/webservess/chapter/ch06.html#_Ref524606239) which also has a pretty illustrative example.

Comment: I need that to fix WSDL that are not compatible with protocol based on what is designed.